# Authlogic plugin with Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do i set up authlogic plugin in my application run on rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2 .

Comment: I really recommend you ask a more detailed question in the future. SO shouldn't become your google; try google, then ask questions when you have problems.

Comment: I put the following code into my GEM file  gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3' and gave command rails g authlogic:session user_session and i got the error " Could not find generator authlogic:session" I am using Ruby 1.9.1 and rails 3

Comment: Well, if you would have read the blogpost that was linked below, you could just use `gem 'authlogic'`.

Comment: Also, just to make it clear: rails3 only works on ruby 1.8.7 or ruby 1.9.2, NOT on 1.9.1 (not sure which you are using, every time you mention the version it changes).

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.dixis.com/?p=352